# How can get data from database based on the url? Django

Tags: python, django

I have some semi-static pages in my Django app that get some information from the database (Page name, headline, etc..).

Currently, for every page, I need to create a separate url in urls.py and pass the page_name.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'second', views.page, {'page_name': 'second'}),
    url(r'first', views.page, {'page_name': 'first'})
]
```

Is there a way I can get the page_name from the url instead and use that to decide what information to get from the database? I was trying something like this with page_name being a model field.

```
url(r'^(?P<page_name>.*/)', views.page)
```

So as I understand it, I need to pass `<page_name>` to the view. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Yes of course there is. This is the fundamental way that Django works, and is fully covered in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can & should use

```
url(r'^(?P<page_name>.*/)', views.page)
```

Although, this should be at the very last element of your `urlpatterns` list since it will capture essentially everything in the url.

Your view should then accept the parameter as the 2nd argument. e.g.

```
# views.py
def page(request, page_name):
    # use the page_name argument as you like
```